# Magento 2 - How to insert manufacturer link inside the product title

Tags: magento2, php

I have product titles all with this structure:

**NAPAPIJRI**
**Men's organic cotton crewneck T-shirt**

Live example: https://www.push96.com/en/napapijri---mens-organic-cotton-crewneck-t-shirt-np0a4eob041.html

I want to link the brand name (in this case the word "**NAPAPIJRI**") to the "view all products of this brand" (in this case "storeurl/brands/napapijri.html". Is this possible?

PS: the brand name is always before 'br' tag

Comment: Yes, possible, did you know from where currently that brand name show>

Comment: It's the tilte of the item, imported from csv. 
I need a php solution for product view, the brand name is always the word in the first line (before br tag). I.E. "NAPAPIJRI" should be "storeurl/brands/napapijri.html, while "TIMBERLAND" shuld be "storeurl/brands/timberland.html. Sometimes brand name is setup from 2/3 words like "POLO RALPH LAUREN" and in this case the url should be "storeurl/brands/polo_ralph_lauren.html"